# ActionFilterAttribute is getting called for all actions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

Maybe I have misunderstood the point of the ActionFilterAttribute, but what I have now is the following:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    //do something useful here
  }
}
```

Then in my Home controller, I have the following action methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [MyCustom]
  public ActionResult Test()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

What I would expect now is that `OnActionExecuting` gets fired when I try to access the `/Home/Test`, but not when I try to access `/Home/Index`.

However, it gets fired for both action methods. I have also verified inside `OnActionExecuting` that there is in fact the `Index` action that is getting called.

Are there any possibility of having `OnActionExecuting` only getting called when you call a action method that is marked with the attribute?

Comment: remove the one which is presant in global.asax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check whether `MyCustomAttribute` is present in `GlobalFilters` collection in `Global.asax`.

Comment: That solved it. It started out as a global filter before I made it into a filterattribute instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen Could you perhaps elaborate what you did to solve it? I am having the same issue, if I add it to global filters, it executes on every action. If I don't add it, then it never executes. Where should I be adding it? I don't see another type of Filters to add it to.

Comment: You  shouldn't need to add it anywhere special. If you debug it, can you check if it enters OnActionExecuting at all?